# Вывод текста командной строкой из буфера обмена

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Я скопировал текст в буфер. Можно ли командной строкой его вывести из буфера в, скажем, текстовой документ?

Answer (score 2):

[Здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cmd-bat/thread784922.html) одно решение (ответ пользователя Dragokas)

[Здесь](https://windowsnotes.ru/powershell-2/rabotaem-s-buferom-obmena-iz-komandnoj-stroki/) второе решение, если у Вас есть PowerShell

Если вкратце, стандартных средств cmd для Вашей задачи не предусматривает. Необходима либо PowerShell (как во [второй](https://windowsnotes.ru/powershell-2/rabotaem-s-buferom-obmena-iz-komandnoj-stroki/) ссылке), либо стороннее ПО(как в [первой](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cmd-bat/thread784922.html) ссылке).

Для помещения текста В буфер обмена существует стандартная утилита clip. Подробнее `clip /?` в cmd.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вторую ссылку я вчера сам находил. Блин, наверное, вариант с PowerShell не подойдет: запуск сторонней программы... А вот вы говорите: "если он есть", А что, его может и не быть? У меня на компе уже третья система (все винды). Во всех трех он присутствовал изначально.

Comment: @mathem Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за ответ или отметьте его как решение, если он был полезен. PowerShell есть в ОС, начиная с Win7. Например, если у Вас XP, его не будет.